# Мобильная версия → Передать точку в приложение яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть на сайте яндекс карта, которая получает точки через LoadingObjectManager. Пользователь может выбрать точку, и нажать на кнопку «Открыть в Яндекс.Картах» которая открывает приложение Я.Карты с такой же долготой, шириной и зумом, что выбрал пользователь. Но там нет выбранной пользователем точки.

Как передать точку в приложение яндекс.карт?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение своей проблемы. Если точку добавить не посредственно на карту, то переходя по кнопке «Открыть в Яндекс.Картах» точка отобразится. Не в кластер, не в коллекцию, не в ObjectManager, а именно на карту:

```
yandexMap.geoObjects.add(placemark);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё подробно расписано с примерами в API Яндекс карт [JavaScript API -> Песочница](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark)

Comment: К сожалению, вы не поняли моего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно генерировать кастомную ссылку/кнопку по [инструкции](https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html#yandexmaps-web__showpoint) Яндекс, в которую пробрасывать текущий центр карты [getCenter()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#method_detail__getCenter) и масштаб [getZoom()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#method_detail__getZoom).